# Selenium::WebDriver::Error - Drag and drop action using WATIR

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, automated-tests, watir

We are trying to simulate a drag and drop action using WATIR, however, we seem to be getting some strange errors in return.

First, we store the 'drag item' and its destination:

```
drag = @browser.trs(:draggable => 'true')
drop = drag[0]
destination = drag[1]
```

The first test we ran combined mouse events:

```
drop.fire_event("onmousedown")
@browser.driver.action.click_and_hold(drop).perform
@browser.driver.action.move_to(destination).click.perform
drop.fire_event("onmouseup")
```

The second test we ran used the drag and drop method:
`@browser.driver.action.drag_and_drop_by(drop, 0, 500).perform`

However, both attempts result in the same error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError: data did not match any variant of untagged enum PointerActionItem at line 1 column 225
./features/W1-Administering_a_Shotlist/W1.1-Shotlists/step_definitions/W1.1.4-Reorder_Shotlist.rb:10:in `/^SA drag the selected shotlist to reorder$/'
./features/W1-Administering_a_Shotlist/W1.1-Shotlists/W1.1.4-Reorder_Shotlist.feature:9:in `When SA drag the selected shotlist to reorder'
```

We think that this error refers to the `@browser.driver.action.` reference in both methods, but are unsure how to resolve this.

Any advice would be most welcome!

---

**Edit 26/11/2018**

As per suggestions below, we tried the `drag_and_drop_on` method using the following code:

```
draggable = @browser.trs(:draggable => 'true')
target = draggable[0]
destination = draggable[1]
target.drag_and_drop_on destination
sleep(5)
```

While this produced no errors, it also didn't seem to produce any results (i.e. moving the `target` element to the position of the `destination` element).

Comment: You might want to double-check you're passing the right arguments. From the examples, your `drop` might be a `String` (ie the `drop = drop.text`) or a `Watir::Element`. The Selenium methods will expect a `Selenium::WebDriver::Element`. Using @titusfortner's answer will simplify a lot since you can stick with `Watir::Element`.

Comment: @JustinKo sorry, that was just a typo from formatting the code for this question (has been fixed above)

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by a bug in geckodriver 0.22 https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1375

Try downgrading geckodriver and see if it works.

Watir has a direct method:

```
draggable.drag_and_drop_on droppable
```

Comment: thanks for your response - we actually tried the `drag_and_drop_on` method a while back - doesn't seem to produce any errors nor any results (I have edited the question to include this example). Any thoughts on why this might be the case?

Comment: If you get something working without the watir method and the watir method does not work, can you let me know? The Watir approach should be doing the Selenium calls that you need without having to deal with action class at all.

Comment: for the most recent test (added to the question above) we used the exact same code you mention in your answer (w/o reference the action class): `target.drag_and_drop_on destination`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for us - it doesn't complete the drag and drop action, nor does it provoke any errors.

Comment: the same (lack of results) also occurs when running the tests on Chrome.

Comment: Can you run it with `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug` and link to a gist of the results?

Comment: Sure thing, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ryanachten/c48c36903f3b2facf9c645a1469f0281) when placing the `:debug` _before_ `target.drag_and_drop_on destination`. Placing it _after_  `drag_and_drop_on` simply results in: `Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout`

Comment: This is showing an exception, not a lack of results. Is this what happens for both Chrome & Firefox? Is the website public such that we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: We just ran the debug command again on both browsers - the results are actually very different. Here are some new gists for [Chrome](https://gist.github.com/ryanachten/dca47cfa2156405f543a1ab2edea34c3) and [Firefox](https://gist.github.com/ryanachten/ed0a9129c0305c62ae0b16ffda31b62b). Unfortunately, the test codebase isn't open, but the test site is [public](http://test.branzartisan.com) if you want to check it out.

Comment: So, there's a bug in chromedriver where it hangs. I don't actually see any of the actions class interactions in Firefox log. I'm expecting to see a reference to an actions endpoint (`session/{session id}/actions`) https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#perform-actions
What version of Firefox & geckodriver?

Comment: Oh right, yeah can't see any references to actions in any of the logs we have produced. The geckodriver version is `0.23.0` and the Firefox version is `63.0.3 (64- bit)`

Comment: Hard to debug further without seeing the commands executed. That being said, it appears the bug is presumably addressed in Firefox 64 which should be released next week: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1491751